# Bootstrap navbar with collapsed menu icon

Tags: html, bootstrap

On this bootstrap starter template:

[image]

when the browser gets narrow the navigation bar links/buttons collapse into one icon in top-right corner like this:

[image]

I would like to have this collapsed "icon" as default like on the picture above. So that the navbar links are available after the user clicks that top-right collapsed button.

How to do that?

This is the source code of the template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: The answer to this question is on Stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622291/bootstrap-navbar-with-collapsed-menu-icon-how-to/37622958#37622958

Comment: Off-topic and already posted on Stack Overflow. Please do not cross post.

Comment: should i delete the question??? sorry i'm new here....what kind of questions are asked here?

Comment: No, because someone has already left an answer. Just in future bare in mind that Cross Posting is not allowed, thanks.

Comment: @lewis4u See the help centre at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help for details on what can be asked here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the place for these types of questions, you should use stackoverflow.

However one way to deal with this is to edit the bootsrap source file. On line 4321 of bootstrap.css you will find the following:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Change the above media query to display the navbar-toggle (which is the button) at whatever screen size you want.

```
From the bootstrap definition:
Device Width        Container Width
1200px or higher    1170px (large screens - large desktops)
992px to 1199px     970px (medium screens - small desktops/laptops)
768px to 991px      750px (small screens - tablets)
Less than 768px     auto (extra small screens - phones)
```

You may have to make some other changes, but I don't have time to sift through what those are because I'm on my way out the door, but this should at least show you where to look. You could also just overwrite this in your style.css with the !important tag.

Comment: Thank you for the answer....i asked the same question on Stack Overflow and someone just answered it! I thought i should ask here....What kind of questions are asked here anyway???

Comment: Webmasters are typically people who manage websites, servers, domains, online marketing and SEO...the business side of websites. Most of the content here is for SEO related purposes. Your question is related to development...for general programming questions and development questions you go to stackoverflow.